# configure raspberry pi from c program

Tags: raspi-config

can I write a piece of code that enables serial port and camera without using raspi-config?  I would like to auto-config modules without manually using raspi-config to do so.

Comment: Sure but it is probably a waste of time, particularly if most of what `raspi-config` does is call binaries (that were mostly written in C); you either re-write all that or just make bunches of `system()` or fork/exec calls.  The only reason to want to do that is because C is the only language you know -- which is fair enough, but a shell script to do this would be very, very simple, especially since you can get the content from the `raspi-config` source (it's a shell script).

Comment: BTW, if you want to know "how to **automate** configuring the camera like raspi-config", that is a very fair and good question -- just don't tack "in C" on it ;)

Answer (score 2):

`raspi-config` is a bash script, so you can read it with a text editor.

The file can be found here `/usr/bin/raspi-config`

But there is no need to do a C program, you could simply use the bash script and tweak it after your needs.

Comment: Or use raspi-config in non-interactive mode, by calling it with command-line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Look at what raspi-config does and convert those actions to the programming language of your choice.